# Arc intersection on a sphere

Tags: spherical-geometry

**Background:** my JavaScript library https://github.com/mistic100/Photo-Sphere-Viewer allows to create 2D polygons overlaying a spherical photo. Polygons are defined by a serie a longitude/latitude points. Spherical coordinates are then projected on the camera near frustrum. This works for small polygons but not for big ones when points are behind the camera.

**Long story short:** I would like to compute intermediary points on the circle delimiting the "front half-sphere" (the one rendered by the camera).

---

The question:

[image: sphere-surface-intersection]
[GeoGebra source file](http://www.sendbox.fr/decb4a6772dd1c10/sphere-surface-intersection.ggb)

**We have :**

- a red sphere centered on 0,0,0 of radius 1
- a black circle of radius 1 and always centered on 0,0,0. So this circle can be any big circle of the sphere.
- An blue arc BD on the sphere surface (here there are 3 arcs but the question is only for one). The arc is only known by its points B and D, only the shortest arc between these points is interesting.

**Want I need :** the coordinates of point H, intersection of arc BD and the black circle.

I only have basic trigonometry knowledge (I forgot almost all my math courses !) and I can't get my head of this and find where to start...

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each great circle on a sphere centered at the origin corresponds to a unique plane through the origin; the intersection of two great circle arcs can be computed using the corresponding planes and linear algebra.

The procedure below assumes $B$ and $D$ do not lie on a diameter of the sphere (i.e., are distinct and not antipodal).

**Synopsis**: Convert $B$ and $D$ to Cartesian coordinates, and let $N$ be a (non-zero) normal vector to the plane of the black circle. If
$$
n = \frac{B \times D}{\|B \times D\|},\qquad
v = n \times B,
$$
then
$$
H = \frac{-(N \cdot v)B + (N \cdot B)v}{\|-(N \cdot v)B + (N \cdot B)v\|}.
$$
(This gives Cartesian coordinates, of course, which may need to be converted back to spherical, the details of which depend on your conventions for spherical coordinates.)

---

**Details**: Convert the spherical coordinates of $B$ and $D$ to Cartesian spatial coordinates using your favorite convention. For example, if $\theta$ denotes longitude (with the positive $x$-axis on the prime meridian) and $\phi$ latitude, then
$$
(x, y, z) = (\cos\theta \cos\phi, \sin\theta \cos\phi, \sin\phi),\qquad
-\pi < \theta \leq \pi,\ -\pi/2 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2.
\tag{1}
$$
The normalized cross product
$$
n = \frac{B \times D}{\|B \times D\|}
$$
is orthogonal to the plane $P$ containing the spherical arc $BD$. (In the preceding formula, $B$ and $D$ denote Cartesian coordinate vectors obtained from (1).) The unit vector
$$
v = n \times B
$$
lies in $P$, is orthogonal to $B$, and "points toward $D$" in the following sense: Every point of the spherical arc through $B$ and $D$ has the form
$$
B \cos t + v \sin t
\tag{2}
$$
for some $t$ with $0 < t \leq \arccos(B \cdot D) < \pi$.

The point $H$ you seek is the unique point of the form (2) lying in the plane $P'$ of your black circle. To find this point, let $N$ denote a non-zero normal vector of $P'$; the point (2) lies in $P'$ if and only if
$$
0 = N \cdot (B \cos t + v \sin t)
  = (N \cdot B) \cos t + (N \cdot v) \sin t.
\tag{3}
$$
A bit of algebra (rearranging (3) and substituting into (2)) gives
$$
H = \frac{-(N \cdot v)B + (N \cdot B)v}{\|-(N \cdot v)B + (N \cdot B)v\|}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it at once.